# Socket.setSoTimeOut() not triggering

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm trying to trigger the said timeOut but to no avail. here is my code.

```
socket = new Socket();
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port), timeOut);
socket.setSoTimeout(pingTimeOut);
bufferOut = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
bufferIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
socketSubject.onNext(new Pair<>(false,"Connected"));
Timber.d("Connected.");
```

and

```
while (isRunning){
    //char[] incoming = new char[4096];
    //int length =  bufferIn.read(incoming);
    //message = String.copyValueOf(incoming,0, length);
    message = bufferIn.readLine();
    if (!message.isEmpty()){
        Timber.d(message);
    }
}
```

I'm deliberately not sending a reply(from the server) after sending a ping message to trigger soTimeOut.

Comment: I think you should call `socket.setSoTimeout(pingTimeOut);` before connecting the socket.

Comment: @Wizard thanks but still doesn't work.

Comment: @Wizard You think so why? What difference will it make? What does `connect()` have to do with it?

Comment: @EJP sir can you point out what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Not until you post the server code. One problem is that you are ignoring end of stream, on which this code will get an NPE. You need to check the result of `readLine()` for null, and `break` if you get it. But @Wizard is completely incorrect. You can call `setSoTimeout()` any time you like after socket creation, and as many times you like, and with as many different values as you like. It will affect the next read operation.

Comment: And it's not clear why you're expecting to receive blank lines (empty messages).

Comment: @EJP ahh I see. so setSoTimeOut() is dependent on server code right? unfortunately I have no access to that. does null check on readLine() catches network failure on server side? as for checking of blank lines I forgot why maybe because I am getting empty message from server.

Comment: No, it isn't dependent on the server, apart from the actual timing, and I didn't say otherwise. We need to see the server code to be able to analyzer and possibly try to reproduce the problem. The null check detects end of stream, as I said. Network failure so are detected as timeouts or `IOExceptions`. You can only be getting empty messages if he server sends them. If you can't post the serve code you need to provide the application protocol.

Comment: Ok. we're using local tcp. as for network failure I get that timeout if the network failure is on the client side but if the server disabled its network the client doesn't detect that. That is why we're trying to implement ping pong.

Comment: I do not understand. What does 'network failure on the client side' even mean? The network is *between* the client and the server, not on one side or the other. The only way this code can not throw `SocketTimeoutException` is if data or an EOS arrives before the timeout period elapses after the read starts, or another `IOException` occurs within that period.

Comment: sorry what I'm trying to say is the server's physical connection to AP. anyway thank you very much for helping out.